# React-Router will not render components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and am trying to learn to use React-Router v5. For some reason, my components will not render through the router. Once in my App.js file, I manually rendered my Login.js from there and when I would press buttons within Login.js, router would not change components but it would change the url. I have looked far and wide and I can't seem to find a fix, I feel like it is something simple I overlooked. Here is my code.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App.js'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ),
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../index.css';
import routes from '../routes.js';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="HomeNavBar">
                <routes />           
            </div>   
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Router, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Import all page components here
 */
import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import Register from './components/Register.js';

/**
 * All routes go here.
 * Don't forget to import the components above after adding new route.
 */
 export default function routes(props) {
    return (
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/Login' component={withRouter(Login)}/>
          <Route path='/Register' component={withRouter(Register)}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={withRouter(Login)}/>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../index.css';
import { Link, withRouter, Router } from 'react-router-dom'

class Login extends React.Component{

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div class = "topnav">
                    <Link to="/">
                      <button class="HomeButton" id="b" href="#home">CollectR</button>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/Register">
                      <button id="a">SignUp</button>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/Login">
                      <button id="a" href="#Login">Login</button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div id="logo">CollectR</div>

                <div>
                    <form id="loginform">
                        <label id="loginregistertext">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="logintextbox" />

                        <label id="loginregistertext">Password</label>
                        <input type="Password" id="logintextbox" />

                        <button id="button">Login </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Can you capitalize Routes? `<Routes />`

Comment: Have you tried removing withRouter and just passing the component name by itself into the Route i.e.  ` <Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>`? Here is the documentation for withRouter, maybe it doesn't do what you think it does: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need like this (taken from react-router-dom documentation):

```
export default function App() {
return (
<Router>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
        renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
);
}
```